# jQuery File Upload “Error Empty file upload result” in mvc 5

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-plugins

I used `jQuery File Upload` in my view. But when upload file,I get error like this (**Empty file upload result**):

[image]

**Action**

```
   [HttpPost]
        public virtual ActionResult UploadImage(IList<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
        {
            var lstUploadReults = new List<UploadFileResult>(files.Count);

            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                if (file.ContentLength <= 0) continue;

                var guid = Guid.NewGuid();
                var fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
                var fileName = $"{guid}{fileExtension}";
                var path = Server.MapPath(TmpPath) + fileName;
                file.SaveAs(path);

                var thumbnailFileName = $"{guid}-thumb{fileExtension}";

                var fileSize = file.ContentLength;

                GenerateProductThumbnailImage(file.InputStream, Server.MapPath(TmpPath) + thumbnailFileName);

                lstUploadReults.Add(new UploadFileResult
                {
                    Url = Url.Content(TmpPath + fileName),
                    Name = file.FileName,
                    DeleteType = "Post",
                    DeleteUrl = Url.Action(MVC.baseadmin.Upload.ActionNames.DeleteFile, MVC.baseadmin.Upload.Name, new {  fileName }),
                    Size = fileSize,
                    ThumbnailUrl = Url.Content(TmpPath + thumbnailFileName),
                    Type = file.ContentType
                });
            }


            return Json(new { Files = lstUploadReults.ToArray() });
        }
```

**View**

```
@using Newtonsoft.Json
@using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization
@model  Model.Adminmodal.Product.AddPicture

<style>
    .ui-state-highlight {
        height: 100px;
        background-color: #ccc !important;
    }

    #tblProductImages td {
        text-align: center;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }

    #tblProductImages .size {
        direction: ltr;
        unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
        text-align: center;
    }

    #tblProductImages .name {
        direction: ltr;
        unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .ui-sortable-helper {
        display: table !important;
        background-color: white;
    }

    div.editable-input input {
        direction: ltr;
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>

<div  id="productImageTab">
    <div id="fileupload">
        <div class="row fileupload-buttonbar">
            <div class="col-lg-7">
                <!-- The fileinput-button span is used to style the file input field as button -->
                <span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
                    <span>انتخاب تصاویر...</span>
                    <input type="file" name="files" multiple>
                </span>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary start">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></i>
                    <span>شروع آپلود</span>
                </button>
                <button type="reset" class="btn btn-warning cancel">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></i>
                    <span>لغو آپلود</span>
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger delete">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
                    <span>حذف</span>
                </button>
                <input type="checkbox" class="toggle">
                <!-- The global file processing state -->
                <span class="fileupload-process"></span>
            </div>
            <!-- The global progress state -->
            <div class="col-lg-5 fileupload-progress fade">
                <!-- The global progress bar -->
                <div class="progress progress-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
                    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" style="width: 0;"></div>
                </div>
                <!-- The extended global progress state -->
                <div class="progress-extended">&nbsp;</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- The table listing the files available for upload/download -->
        <table id="tblProductImages" role="presentation" class="table table-striped"><tbody class="files"></tbody></table>
    </div>
    @*@if (Model.Images != null && Model.Images.Any())
    {
        <input id="productImagesData" type="hidden" value="@JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.Images, new JsonSerializerSettings()
{
    ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver(),
})" />
    }*@

    <script id="template-upload" type="text/x-tmpl">
        {% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
        <tr class="template-upload fade">
            <td>
                <p class="preview"></p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p class="name">{%=file.name%}</p>
                <strong class="error text-danger"></strong>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p class="size">Processing...</p>
                <div class="progress progress-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuenow="0"><div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" style="width:0%;"></div></div>
            </td>
            <td>
                {% if (!i && !o.options.autoUpload) { %}
                <button class="btn btn-primary start" disabled>
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></i>
                    <span>شروع کن</span>
                </button>
                {% } %}
                {% if (!i) { %}
                <button class="btn btn-warning cancel">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></i>
                    <span>بیخیال شو</span>
                </button>
                {% } %}
            </td>
        </tr>
        {% } %}
    </script>
    <script id="template-download" type="text/x-tmpl">
        {% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
        <tr class="template-download fade">
            <td style="display:none !important;">
                @Html.Hidden("Images.Index", "{%= file.name %}")
                @Html.Hidden("Images[{%= file.name %}].Id", "{%= file.id %}")
                @Html.Hidden("Images[{%= file.name %}].Name", "{%= file.name %}")
                @Html.Hidden("Images[{%= file.name %}].Order", "{%= file.order %}")
                @Html.Hidden("Images[{%= file.name %}].ThumbnailUrl", "{%= file.thumbnailUrl %}")
                @Html.Hidden("Images[{%= file.name %}].Url", "{%= file.url %}")
                @Html.Hidden("Images[{%= file.name %}].Size", "{%= file.size %}")
                @Html.Hidden("Images[{%= file.name %}].DeleteUrl", "{%= file.deleteUrl %}")
                @Html.Hidden("Images[{%= file.name %}].ProductId", Model.ProductId)
            </td>

            <td>
                <span class="preview">
                    {% if (file.thumbnailUrl) { %}
                    <a href="{%=file.url%}" title="{%=file.name%}" download="{%=file.name%}" data-gallery><img src="{%=file.thumbnailUrl%}"></a>
                    {% } %}
                </span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p class="name">
                    {% if (file.url) { %}
                    <a href="{%=file.url%}" title="{%=file.name%}" download="{%=file.name%}" {%=file.thumbnailUrl?'data-gallery':''%}>{%=file.name%}</a>
                    {% } else { %}
                    <span>{%=file.name%}</span>
                    {% } %}
                </p>
                {% if (file.error) { %}
                <div><span class="label label-danger">Error</span> {%=file.error%}</div>
                {% } %}
            </td>
            <td>
                <span class="size">{%=o.formatFileSize(file.size)%}</span>
            </td>
            <td>
                {% if (file.deleteUrl) { %}
                <button class="btn btn-danger delete" data-type="Post" data-url="{%=file.deleteUrl%}" {% if (file.deleteWithCredentials) { %} data-xhr-fields='{"withCredentials":true}' {% } %}>
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
                    <span>حذف</span>
                </button>
                <input type="checkbox" name="delete" value="1" class="toggle">
                {% } else { %}
                <button class="btn btn-warning cancel">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></i>
                    <span>بیخیال4</span>
                </button>
                {% } %}
            </td>
        </tr>
        {% } %}
    </script>


    <a href="@Url.Action(MVC.baseadmin.Product.ActionNames.Index, MVC.baseadmin.Product.Name)" class="btn azm-social azm-btn azm-border-bottom azm-facebook" id="btncreate" style="border:solid 1px #ffffff">
        بازگشت
        <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i>
    </a>
    </div>

<link href="~/Content/bootstrap-editable/bootstrap-editable.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/select2.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Scripts/jQuery-File-Upload/css/jquery.fileupload.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//blueimp.github.io/Gallery/css/blueimp-gallery.min.css">


<script src="~/Scripts/jquery2-min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jQuery-File-Upload/js/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jQuery-File-Upload/js/vendor/tmpl.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jQuery-File-Upload/js/vendor/load-image.all.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jQuery-File-Upload/js/vendor/canvas-to-blob.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jQuery-File-Upload/js/jquery.iframe-transport.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jQuery-File-Upload/js/jquery.fileupload.js"></script>



<script src="~/Scripts/jQuery-File-Upload/js/jquery.fileupload-process.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jQuery-File-Upload/js/jquery.fileupload-image.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jQuery-File-Upload/js/jquery.fileupload-validate.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jQuery-File-Upload/js/jquery.fileupload-ui.js"></script>
<script src="//blueimp.github.io/Gallery/js/jquery.blueimp-gallery.min.js"></script>
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/manage-product")


   <script type="text/javascript">

        var productId = parseInt('@Model.ProductId');
        $("#productImageTab").imageTab({
            fileUploadId: "fileupload",
            uploadUrl: "@Url.Action(MVC.baseadmin.Upload.ActionNames.UploadImage, MVC.baseadmin.Upload.Name )",
            tblFilesId: "tblProductImages",
            uploadedFilesId: "productImagesData"
        });

</script>
```

**Plugin(imagetab.js)**

```
(function () {

    $.fn.imageTab = function (options) {

        var defaults = {
            fileUploadId: null,
            uploadUrl: null,
            tblFilesId: null,
            uploadedFilesId: null
        };

        var settings = $.extend(defaults, options);

        var $fileUpload = $("#" + settings.fileUploadId).fileupload({
            url: settings.uploadUrl,
            formData: function (form) {
                return form.find("input[type='file']").serializeArray();
            },
            autoUpload: true,
            maxFileSize: 99900000,
            acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i
        });

        $("#" + settings.tblFilesId + " tbody").sortable({
            items: '> tr',
            revert: true,
            forcePlaceholderSize: true,
            placeholder: 'ui-state-highlight',
            cursor: "move",
            start: function (event, ui) {
                // Build a placeholder cell that spans all the cells in the row
                var cellCount = 0;
                $('td, th', ui.helper).each(function () {
                    // For each TD or TH try and get it's colspan attribute, and add that or 1 to the total
                    var colspan = 1;
                    var colspanAttr = $(this).attr('colspan');
                    if (colspanAttr > 1) {
                        colspan = colspanAttr;
                    }
                    cellCount += colspan;
                });

                // Add the placeholder UI - note that this is the item's content, so TD rather thanTR
                ui.placeholder.html('<td colspan="' + cellCount + '">&nbsp;</td>');
            }

        });


        var imagesDataInput = $("input#" + settings.uploadedFilesId).val();

        if (imagesDataInput != undefined) {
            var imagesData = $.parseJSON(imagesDataInput);
            $fileUpload.fileupload('option', 'done')
                .call($fileUpload[0], $.Event('done'), { result: { files: imagesData } });
        }

        return this;
    }

})();
```

It would be very helpful if someone could explain solution for this problem.

Comment: Just one question....why `virtual`? ...are you overriding that method on another place?

Comment: thanks  iam dont use another place

Comment: Then you dont need to make it virtual...

Comment: how sloved problem ?? virtual removed but exits problem